# Why does meld take such a long time to start on a remote machine?

Tags: linux, performance, python, meld

I use a machine remotely on which several people have remote access. One of them messed around with the Python versions, installed a newer version maybe, not exactly sure. Assume I have no access to him. Now, the main pythonic thing I'm using on that machine is running [meld](https://meldmerge.org/) - a python utility for diff'ing and merging files.

For a while, meld wasn't running at all. Then that other user fixed/changed things again, and meld now works. However - it's taking > 20 seconds to start (!)

After startup, meld is quite responsive, so it's not networking issues AFAICT.

How can I determine what causes this startup delay?

Notes:

- I'm not an expert in Python.
- The Linux distribution is SLES 15.
- I can become root if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experience this very slow start of `meld` on a headless Debian 11 server accessed through SSH with -X forwarding enabled.

The problem seems to be described in this bug report:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/-/issues/484

Not sure if your problem is the same, but the suggested solution or workaround seems to work for me. Before using Meld, start

```
dbus-launch --exit-with-session /bin/bash
```

Comment: So, you suggest I enter a subshell via dbus-launch, and invoke meld from there?

Comment: @einpoklum: yes, it sounded strange to me too, and I don't quite understand the role of dbus in this, but it does work for me.

Comment: Will try it next time I'm on that machine.

Comment: I'm having the same problem (even `meld --version` is slow), but this command didn't help.

Comment: This works! How weird

Answer (score 0):

The advice from the other answer (https://superuser.com/a/1729262/21952) didn't work for me on Debian bookworm. I suspect this has something to do with changes in DBus.

For some reason, the following commands helped. I'm not sure what the side-effects are; I hope somebody will share a better workaround:

```
sudo apt remove dbus-user-session
sudo apt install dbus-x11
```

I got the idea from reading `apt info dbus-user-session`.

Comment: What are other effects of this removal and addition?